# Two buttons and text with different align

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have this code of popup.htlm file:

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <select style="width: 100%;"
      multiple id="HLSlist">
   </select>
   <span style="display:inline">
      <button type="button" id="Deletebut">Delete</button>
      <button type="button" id="OpenAllbut">Open All</button>
      <t id='VFlagged'>0</t>
   </span>
   <hr>
   <input type="checkbox" id="BlurThumbs">
   <t>Blur Thumbnails</t>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-width: 200px;
}

t {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

I want that the text goes to the right side, like appear on the picture:
[image]

Comment: Are these screenshots from the same browser?

Comment: Easiest way to help you is if you can throw an example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: There is a `<t>` element?

Comment: Just put relivant js in http://jsfiddle.net/PNkTU/

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: @cimmanon ... I was wondering the same thing? I thought maybe it was just some new tag I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply float it.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xkt9/1/) - it has the results you expect.

```
#VFlagged {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Some padding might be necessary - I added 10px..

Also.. I changed the `t` element to a `span`..

Comment: @shunamicode Which "Related" answer worked for you? It may be helpful to others if this question is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119976/simple-css-problem-title-text-on-upper-left-button-on-the-upper-right?rq=1

Comment: not the same problem but very similar. now i have done it. it was "float".